# Escribir en archivo la salida estándar de subproceso externo cuando esta contiene acentos

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo este código en Python 3, pero el problema es que al escribir en el archivo no me escribe los acentos. He intentado abrirlo en utf-8 pero nada, no hay manera.

```
import subprocess

f = open('ipconfigsalida.txt','w',encoding='utf-8')
salida = subprocess.call('ipconfig',stdout=f)
salida2 = str(salida)    
f.write(salida2)
f.close()
```

Comment: Está usando la codificación local, posiblemente DOS CP850, abre el archivo con esta codificación en un editor para confirmarlo. ¿que versión de Python 3 estás usando?

Comment: estoy usando python 3.6.4

Comment: estoy usando cp1252

Comment: pero si abro el archivo con utf-8 deberia escribir los acentos o no? es que no entiendo...

Comment: No hay manera de que muestre los malditos acentos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que el proceso *`ipconfig`* retorna el texto de salida usando la página codificación de 8-bit  activa para la consola. La solución pasa por decodificar la salida dependiendo de la codificación local.

Dado que usas Python 3.6 te recomiendo que no uses `subprocess.call`, usa [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) (añadida en Python 3.5 y que actúa como wrapper de `subprocess.Popen`) en su lugar.

Una opción es hacer algo así:

```
import subprocess



with open('ipconfigsalida.txt','w', encoding="utf-8") as f:  
    p = subprocess.run('ipconfig', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                        universal_newlines=True, encoding="cp850")
    f.write(p.stdout)
```

Comment: Problema resuelto! muchas gracias por la ayuda FJSevilla

Comment: Hola @Juan. Si esta respuesta solucionó tu problema, por favor considerá aceptarla haciendo click en el ✓ a la izquierda de ésta, debajo de las flechas de votación

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomiendo revisar el uso que le estás dando a subprocess, no estoy seguro de como funciona pero si hago algo como lo siguiente me funciona muy bien y veo los caracteres con acentos escritos en el archivo f.txt:

```
f = open('f.txt','w',encoding='utf-8')
f.write('áéíóúñ')
f.close()
```

Por cierto estoy usando Ubuntu por lo que para estar seguro que estoy usando python 3 estoy ejecutando mi programa de ejemplo **f.py** de la siguiente manera:

```
python3 f.py
```

Saludos.

Comment: Yo estoy en windows

Comment: Si en lugar de subprocess utilizo os me pasa lo mismo

Comment: import os

f = open('ipconfigsalida.txt','w',encoding='utf-8')
salida = os.popen('ipconfig').read()
f.write(salida)
f.close()